# index.html overwrite through Docker image making

Tags: python, docker, web-applications

amateur author developer running my directory on port 80 to show tkinter windows of a txt file in a /txt to search strings and highlight parts of my novel. When I spun up the image, it totally rewrote my index, which contains lots of bot recommended packages like os codeblock
Here's a little bit of the main loop

```
arch_text = entry.get()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            content = file.read()
            count = content.count(search_text)
            count_label.config(text=f"Occurrences: {count}")
            text_widget.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            occurrences = content.split(search_text)
            for i, occ in enumerate(occurrences[:-1]):
                start_index = text_widget.index(tk.END)
                text_widget.insert(start_index, occ[-150:] + '\n')
                text_widget.insert(tk.END, search_text, "highlight")
                text_widget.tag_add("clip", start_index, tk.END)
                text_widget.tag_configure("highlight", background="yellow")
                text_widget.tag_configure("clip", foreground="blue")
                text_widget.tag_bind("clip", "<Button-1>", show_clip)

def show_clip(event):
    clip_index = text_widget.ta
```

What I'd like is for the tkinter display to print strings from a txt file to a web app display on an index.html which looks somewhat like

Search
        
        
            
            
        
            Generate Random

so basically I want this is Jeopardy online with a lightsail instance.
Sincerley, Rupert

I installed a lot of packages including tkinter. I spun up docker images and checked logs to find I was getting redirect loops, and also I fixed an indent error in the app.py. I haven't imported flask, I haven't git pulled the 

Search





Generate Random

from https://github.com/Nostrathomas0/buel/blob/main/index.html yet